# How to select items in listview printing in print dialog box?

Tags: vb.net

I get an error message since I wanted to print only the selected items in listview. How can I select then print it in print dialog box? 'Items' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection'.

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Items


            e.Graphics.DrawString(lvi.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, H)
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `SelectedItems` are the items there is no need to try and use `.items`

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.SelectedItems

        e.Graphics.DrawString(lvi.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, H)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Me.ListView1.SelectedItems
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lvi.SubItems(1).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, H)
Next
```

To make you understand what was wrong in your code, this is `Me.ListView1.SelectedItems.Items` changed to `Me.ListView1.SelectedItems` and `lvi.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text` is changed to `lvi.SubItems(1).Text`